# Swift 3: How to set up UINavigationBar setBackgroundImage in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I recently migrated from Swift 2 to Swift 3 and I'm stuck on one part.  In my AppDelegate, I'd set up the default settings for the UINavigationBar as coded below.  The challenge I'm having is that the setBackgroundImage is no longer recognized in Swift 3 and I can't find an alternative.

Has anyone had the same issue happen and been able to resolve it?

```
    let turquoiseBackgroundImage:UIImage = UIImage(named: "navigationBarTurqoise")!


    **// TODO Below is not working with Swift 3
    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(turquoiseBackgroundImage, forBarPosition: .Default)**


    // Set up Back button to be white in Navigation bar
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white

    // Font Name and Size of Title in Navigation Bar
    if let font = UIFont(name: "TitilliumWeb-Light", size: 20) {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName : font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white]
    }

    // Remove hairline between navigation bar and anything below such as search bar
    UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()

    // Set up status bar (battery, time, etc.) to white
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
```

Comment: Swift declaration `func setBackgroundImage(_ image: UIImage?, 
                    for state: UIControlState)` https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibutton/1624016-setbackgroundimage, so try  `setBackgroundImage(turquoiseBackgroundImage, for: .default)*`

Comment: **Hint:** Next time just let Xcode auto complete it for you.

Comment: Yes, I tried the auto complete, however, there is no setBackgroundImage function at all under UINavigationBar.appearance()..

There is a setBackgroundImage function under UINavigationBar directly, but it takes a <T> of UINavigationBar as its argument.. Makes no sense? UINavigationBar.setBackgroundImage(<#T##UINavigationBar#>)

Comment: Try opening a new playground file if Xcode starts refusing to automatically complete it for you and try there that it should work

Answer (score 6):

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(turquoiseBackgroundImage, forBarPosition: .Default)
```

rewrite code like this

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(turquoiseBackgroundImage, for: .default)
```